# Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException EmojiCompat is not initialized , library androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I self haven't experienced this crash but some users does get it, when I check the Firebase Crashlytics.

The error in the Firebase:

> Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
> EmojiCompat is not initialized. Please call EmojiCompat.init() first
> com.app.myapp.UserActivity.onCreate
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myapp/com.app.myapp.UserActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #429: Binary XML file line #429: Error inflating class androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView

this is the line #429 in the xml

```
                <androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:maxLines="12"
                    android:paddingTop="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

and I also have this just right below of setContentView(R.layout.activity_user); inside the Oncreate

```
        FontRequest fontRequest = new FontRequest(
                "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
                "com.google.android.gms",
                "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
                R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs);
        EmojiCompat.Config config = new FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(this, fontRequest);
        EmojiCompat.init(config);
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize this library in `application` class or before `setContentView`

```
onCreate(){
FontRequest fontRequest = new FontRequest(
                "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
                "com.google.android.gms",
                "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
                R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs);
        EmojiCompat.Config config = new FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(this, fontRequest);
        EmojiCompat.init(config);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user) // set after initializing

}
```